# Probability of $R=2$ runs among $10$ coin tosses with $7$ heads and $3$ tails $-$ Possible book error?

Tags: probability

Here is the problem:

"A person observes $7$ heads and $3$ tails after tossing a coin $10$ times. What is the probability that the person observed $2$ runs?"

According to John E. Freund (author of *Mathematical Statistics*) the probability of observing $y_1$ runs of object $1$ and $y_2$ runs of object $2$ is $$p(y_1,y_2)=\frac{{n_1 -1 \choose y_1-1}{n_2 - 1 \choose y_2 -1}}{{n_1 +n_2 \choose n_1}}$$

Here, $n_1,n_2$ are the number of times object types $1,2$ appear in your (ordered) sample.

This formula is derived using a "stars and bars" style argument, and I believe the author neglected to consider the type of object apparent in the first run. This consideration would effectively double the probability shown above.

For example, in the outcome $AABBBAABAAAB$ we have $n_a=7,n_b=5,y_a=3, y_b=3,$ and $r=6$. (These are lower case since they are all *observed* quantities.)

You can solve this problem quickly by replacing $n_h=7,n_t=3,y_h=1,y_t=1$ to get a probability of $\frac{1}{120}$.

If we didn't want to use this formula, we can find this probability simply by computing $\mathbb{P}(R=2|N_h=7)$ where $N_h\sim \text{Binomial}(10,1/2)$ is the number of times heads appears.

Clearly the only outcomes in the event $\{R=2\}\cap \{N_h=7\}$ are $$hhhhhhhttt \text{ and }ttthhhhhhh$$

So this probabiltiy is $\mathbb{P}(R=2|N_h=7)=\frac{2 (1/2)^{10}}{{10 \choose 7}(1/2)^{10}}=\frac{1}{60}$ which is exactly twice the probability established by the author.

Thoughts?

Comment: I agree with your calculation.

Comment: What is a "run"?